# From array of objects extract array of property values for items having another property equal to given value

Tags: javascript, arrays

An array is given below. I would like to get the username for every single member of this array whose team is red!

```
const array = [
  {
    username: "john",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },

];
```

I've tried this code:

```
const colorTeam = array.filter(teams=>teams.team === 'red');
console.log('teamColor:', username);
```

It didn't work!

Comment: When you do `console.log('teamColor:', username);`, where is `username` supposed to be coming from? And why is that line not using `colorTeam` from the previous line?

Answer (score 2):

As opposed to `filter()`+`map()` (two passes over the source array), one may use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve that in a single pass (which may give certain performance gain should input array be large enough, or such *filtering* performed often enough):

```js
const array = [{username:"john",team:"red",score:5,items:["ball","book","pen"]},{username:"becky",team:"blue",score:10,items:["tape","backpack","pen"]},{username:"susy",team:"red",score:55,items:["ball","eraser","pen"]},{username:"tyson",team:"green",score:1,items:["book","pen"]}],

      redTeamNames = array.reduce((acc, {username, team}) => 
        (team == 'red' && acc.push(username), acc), [])
        
console.log(redTeamNames)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you wanted?
First we filter objects with `team === red`, then we map the array to contain `username` property only.

```js
const array = [
  {
    username: "john",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },

];

const colorTeam = array
  .filter(teams=>teams.team === 'red')
  .map(user=>user.username);
console.log('teamColor:', colorTeam);
```

Comment: I previously used just those two lines of code:const colorTeam = array
  .filter(teams=>teams.team === 'red'). It shows all features of an array's members that contain team of red color! The line of code .map(user=>user.username); is key line of code! So I grabbed the logic! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

user `Array.filter` followed by `Array.map`:

```js
const array=[{username:"john",team:"red",score:5,items:["ball","book","pen"]},{username:"becky",team:"blue",score:10,items:["tape","backpack","pen"]},{username:"susy",team:"red",score:55,items:["ball","eraser","pen"]},{username:"tyson",team:"green",score:1,items:["book","pen"]}];

let result = array.filter(({team}) => team === "red").map(({username}) => username)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
let newArray = array.filter((el) => el.team==="red" ? el : "").map((el) => el.username);
```

First, filter objects with team property named "red", then use map method to get username properties only.

Comment: Using `.filter()` this way is a bit overkill: `.filter()` returns all items of the source array for which callback passed as an argument evaluates to truthy value, so simple `array.filter((el) => el.team==="red")` (where boolean `true`/`false` is returned) is absolutely enough, and there's no need to overburden that with ternary, returning object (evaluated truthy) or empty string (evaluated falsy).

Comment: And, of course, your approach is nothing different to ***2*** answers posted earlier, so it is not clear which extra value you attempted to bring in, so more comprehensive explanation would make sense.